# Add a dummy row if the record had one occurrence in snapshot

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dummy-variable

```
   YY_MM_CD customerid pol_no   type   WE   WP
2019-07  15680    1313145    new    3     89
2020-01  14672    1418080    renwd  -8    223
2019-01  15681    1213143    new    4      8
2019-01  15683    1213344    new    -6       3
2019-03  14678    1418280    renwd  -66     -7
```

Suppose i am taking data for 2019-20 snapshot for one year and I need to create dummy record for customer id who didn't renwed and are new within the one year time frame 
df1  (for customer id 15681)

```
YY_MM_CD customerid pol_no   type   WE   WP
2019-07  15680    1313145    new    3     89
2020-01  14672    1418080    renwd  -8    223
2019-01  15681    1213143    new    4      8
2020-01  15681    1213143    new    0       0
2019-03  14678    1418280    renwd  -66     -7
```

Comment: Are there customerid in both tables?

Comment: This will give you the true for new customers, `df['type'] = df.groupby(['customerid '])['customerid '].transform(lambda x: x.count()==1)`

Comment: Hi Ron & Xavi .Sorry it is my mistake regarding the above table . Yes there are customer id in both the table . I have some x years of data and i am taking for snapshot of 19-20. Suppose if a customer in this snapshot paid premium on 01/11/2019 the customer didn't paid premium on 01/11/2020 so that record will be not their in data.  I need to created a dummy record for that customer . Like this customer id  15681   and keep their WE and WP as 0 0 since customer didn't paid .